# Google Bigquery query Record data - Patents

Tags: mysql, google-bigquery, record

I'm using [Google Patents Public Dataset](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/public-datasets/google-patents-public-datasets-connecting-public-paid-and-private-patent-data) to extract patent information about pesticides using the CPC code "A01N" PRESERVATION OF BODIES OF HUMANS OR ANIMALS OR PLANTS OR PARTS THEREOF

But while I run the following Query, I don't obtain all the results as If I run a non-unnest query. See both below

```
SELECT patents.country_code, count(DISTINCT publication_number) as quantity
FROM
  `patents-public-data.patents.publications` AS patents,
  UNNEST(title_localized) AS title,
  UNNEST(abstract_localized) AS abstract,
  UNNEST(cpc) AS cpc_code,
  UNNEST(inventor_harmonized) AS inventor,
  UNNEST(assignee_harmonized) AS assignee
WHERE 
  cpc_code.code LIKE '%A01N%'
GROUP BY patents.country_code
ORDER BY quantity DESC
```

| Row | country_code | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | US | 67280 |
| 2 | CN | 59067 |
| 3 | WO | 39560 |
| 4 | EP | 37886 |
| 5 | CA | 23115 |

```
SELECT patents.country_code, count(DISTINCT publication_number) as quantity
FROM
  `patents-public-data.patents.publications` AS patents,
  UNNEST(cpc) AS cpc_code
WHERE 
  cpc_code.code LIKE '%A01N%'
GROUP BY country_code
ORDER BY quantity DESC
```

| Row | country_code | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | US | 77056 |
| 2 | CN | 70654 |
| 3 | EP | 60291 |
| 4 | WO | 39624 |
| 5 | JP | 36135 |

I don't understand why there is a difference between both results as no more filters were applied?
How can I maintain all the rows when I UNNEST more columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the rows in the columns that you are `UNNEST`ing are empty arrays. When you do the implicit `CROSS JOIN`, you're joining on a `NULL` which gives you no results, so some of those rows disappear and your count is lower. If you start commenting out some of those `CROSS JOIN`s you'll see your count start to go up. Since you're not actually using those columns, you should remove them from your query. If you want them later, get the counts first, and then `LEFT JOIN` on something like `1=1`.